# Syntax Error Passing Razor Markup As Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to write a custom control and associated html helper that can have it's output changed by providing a template.  I've found examples of this on the web ([example](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/9/simplifying_html_generation_using_razor_templates%22)) but keep hitting upon a strange syntax error that I don't understand.

Here's a simplified version of what I've got so far:

Method signature that takes the razor template

```cs
public IHtmlString Template<T>(Func<T, object> template) {
    // Implementation not important
}
```

Calling the method in my view:

```vbhtml
@Html.Control(Of Integer)().Template(@<div>@item</div>)
```

However, I keep getting a syntax error which is showing on the closing bracket of the Template method.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here nor could I find any similar problems else where.  Does anyone have any ideas what's going wrong here?

Also yes I realise that the helper is written in c# and the razor is in vb sadly that's the way things are round here.

Comment: You're giving the wrong parameter to the template method. You need to pass a delegate of type `Func<T, object>` like this `@Html.Control(Of Integer)().Template(item =>  string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", item))`

Comment: Yea I've managed to do that, and it's a workaround to the problem I've got, but it's not the nicest.  I'd like to use the functionality that appears to be in c# razor and use it in vb.net.  I'm starting to think that this is one of those c# only features.